Wind sensitivity of star fruit (Carambola) with age
How sensitive are star fruit trees to wind? Especially when they have grown into a tree?
Someone told me they are only sensitive when they are young. Is it true? At what age do they overcome wind sensitivity?
We get sand storms with strong winds here every few weeks in summer. Is it going to work?
I have one spot on the ground to grow either a star fruit or a jujube, and I would prefer to grow star fruit.


These plants do not appreciate windy conditions to grow in - it's best to plan on providing some sort of shelter from the winds you regularly get. In windy areas, they may not achieve their full growth potential - although this information https://edis.ifas.ufl.edu/publication/MG269 is provided for growers in Florida, the section on wind is still relevant wherever you grow it.
